# Simple Linux mailserver for sending "notification" emails

Tags: server, email, notification, postfix

I am looking to set up a simple postfix server on Ubuntu server 12.04 to use for "notifications" from simple equipment like UPS devices. My company is moving to an external hosted provider for our Exchange email services and this would allow simple, preferrably un-authenticated email messages to be sent from the linux box to outside email addresses.  I have a postfix server installed and can use the webmin console gui to send test messages from the primary user account successfully, but so far I am still unable to send from any other "device based" system.

Pointers to a good tutorial or prior posts which my searches did not discover are welcome.

Comment: I got a tip from a friend who is more experienced, and was able to add my local network IP address ranges to the "mynetworks" variable in postfix's main.cf and this allows the devices to send as needed.

Comment: Other than postfix, You might try Mailgun (http://www.mailgun.com).  PHP library is available here: https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php ‎